# Sorting and Keeping Distinct repetitive rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with one column (NAME) containing the following values  A,A,A,B,C,D,D,A,A,A,F,F,E,C,B
I would like to acquire a list of sequence of these values meaning, my result should look like A,B,C,D,AF,E,C,B.

I tried the following code:

```
data <- data %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
arrange(TIME) %>%
distinct(NAME)
```

However, the `distinct` alows one NAME to be included only once in the list/sequence.

Also, tried with library `fastmatch` by specifying `fmatch(NAME, unique(NAME)`, but ran into errors.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What does your data look like? What is the relationship between ID, TIME, and NAME? Can you provide a test data set?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to create groups based on the difference in value between adjacent elements and then `slice` the first row

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
data %>%      
    arrange(ID, TIME) %>%
    group_by(ID, grp = rleid(NAME)) %>%
    slice(1)
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:3, each = 5), TIME = Sys.Date() + 1:15,
         NAME = c("A","A","A","B","C","D","D","A","A","A","F","F","E","C","B"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will edit the data-frame a bit so the answer will need modification. Will do it at the earliest. The group_by (ID) was used as the IDs are repeated as well. Thanks